# Getting data from database leading to endless http calls

Tags: database, angular, typescript

I have one problem. Once I am trying to extract data from database I am getting endless http requests for some reason, which crushing my app. How can I avoid this?

```
readData() {
this.dataService.getData()
  .subscribe(resp => {
    this.data = resp;
    console.log(resp);
  });
```

}

Comment: where is the readData() called?

Comment: please create a https://stackblitz.com/ example with the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "where"?

Comment: If you're calling `this.dataService.getData()` in the constructor or lifecycle hooks while also invoking `readData()` in any of them then that will be your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the readData is invoked during any of these events:

```
ngOnChanges
ngDoCheck
ngAfterContentChecked
ngAfterViewChecked
```

These lifecycle hooks may be invoked multiple times during the life of a component, and can cause multiple http calls to the backend in your case.